# Merging two bytes?

Tags: java, android, byte

I am learning how MIDI works and am wondering how to merge two bytes. There is a paragraph that states the following

“The status and channel Bytes are merged into one byte (00-FF) Because these messages have an MSB (Most Significant Byte) of 1 the command statuses actually begin at 80 hexadecimal (128 and up to 255) The LSB (Least Significant Byte takes a value of 0-F Hexadecimal (0 to 15) to specify which MIDI channel the command will be sent to. A command message tells the MIDI gear to perform certain types of things like play a note, change the volume, add effects, and other types of things. This table shows the different command status and what they do.”

I am not 100% sure what it means by merging Bytes into a byte. Any help would be appreciated. If you could provide an example of how to do this in java with an explanation I’d be even more grateful.

Comment: It looks like the status is shifted left 4 bits to the high nibble and the channel is left in the low nibble. These two values are then ORed together.

Comment: The text you quoted at length answers your question at length. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: im not sure why the doco would refer to the upper and lower 4 bits of a byte as the Most Significant Byte and Least Significant Byte. its misleading to me. what it means is the command value (which is 4 bits long) and the channel value (which is also 4 bits long) are put into 1 byte (total, 8 bits). iv written a synth in C which might be a helpful guide. look at the injectMidi() function where you can see it splits the two halves of the "command". https://github.com/slipperyseal/monty/blob/master/monty.c

Comment: EJP that text does not answer my question. It does not explain in detail what merging to bytes is nor does it give me a detail in code. I’d appreciate it if you only added to the conversation and not add a condescending tone to this thread. I’ll look at that code slipperyseal. I am pretty confortable with the basics of C, being a C++ guy original myself. I wonder why it says merge two bytes into a byte instead of two bits. That is very confusing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `MSB (Most Significant Byte) of 1`. Most Significant Bit.

Comment: `The LSB (Least Significant Byte takes a value of 0-F `. If it was a byte it could have values of 00-FF.

Comment: If there is a MSB and LSB then how many bytes would there be in total? 4 as with an integer?

Comment: What is the difference between a byte of 0-F and a byte of 00-FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to the problem.

```
Byte b1 = 0xF;
Byte b2 = 0xF;
Byte merged = (b1 >> 4 | b2);
```

Byte 1 is shifted four bits to the left to guarantee it is the most significant bit while byte 2 is bitwise or as the least significant bits. The important thing is that the paragraph i posted above says you may merge two bytes together. Both bytes must be at a maximum of 4 bits. If they exceed 8 bits total the result is a short or int based on how large the result is.